# Python pandas, what should I pay attention to when using groupby()

Tags: python, pandas

I got an .tsv file [imdb_actor_edges.tsv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yif3g.png), which includes 287074 rows in total.
I wanna figure out how many times each actor shows up in the file, so here's my code(using python pandas):

```
import pandas as pd

edges = pd.read_csv('imdb_actor_edges.tsv', sep='\t')

edges.loc[:,'edges'] = 1;

df1 = edges[['actor1','edges']]  
df2 = edges[['actor2','edges']]
df1.columns = ['actor','edges']  
df2.columns = ['actor','edges']

edges_sorted = pd.concat([df1,df2],join='inner',ignore_index=True)
edges_sorted.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)

edges_sorted.groupby('actor')['edges'].sum()
```

The problem is that edges_sorted is supposed to be less than 287074*2 rows('cause there're actors who shows more than one time) but actually not. It remains 287074*2 rows and the 'edges' is still 1.

Did I do anything wrong? How can I solve the problem?

Comment: you can use `size` df.groupby('actor')['actor'].size()` but it would be better if you provided a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:-

```
import pandas as pd

edges = pd.read_csv('imdb_actor_edges.tsv', sep='\t')

edges.loc[:,'edges'] = 1;
df1 = edges[['actor1','edges']]  
df2 = edges[['actor2','edges']]
df1.columns = ['actor','edges']  
df2.columns = ['actor','edges']

edges_sorted = pd.concat([df1,df2],join='inner',ignore_index=True)
edges_sorted.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)

result = edges_sorted.groupby('actor').agg(sum)
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
result
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: It works. Appreciation!
But I still wonder why mine doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try replacing your last line with this? ```result = pd.DataFrame(edges_sorted.groupby('actor')['edges'].sum())
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
result```

Comment: event after doing a group_by on edge_sorted, the content is not changed in_place (you have to assign it to some series or df). if that solves your confusion.